# Seg fault from constructor

Tags: c++

I call this code in main()

```
for (COwnerList l=b1.ListOwners(10); !l.AtEnd(); l.Next())
  cout << l.Surname() << ", " << l.Name () << endl;

for (CCarList l=b1.ListCars("Peter","Smith"); !l.AtEnd(); l.Next ())
  cout << l.RZ () << ", " << l.VIN() << endl;

for (COwnerList l=b1.ListOwners(10); !l.AtEnd(); l.Next())
  cout << l.Surname() << ", " << l.Name() << endl;
```

I tried to debug and found out seg fault comes from Constructor of COwnerList

```
COwnerList CRegister::ListOwners    (unsigned int      vin) const
{
    vector<Car>::const_iterator it;
    COwnerList tmp;
    it = lower_bound(byVINList.begin(), byVINList.end(), Car("",vin), cmpVIN);
    if(it != byVINList.end())
        tmp.car = &(*it);
    tmp.in = it->owners.end() - it->owners.begin();
    return tmp;
}
```

constructor im calling looks like this:

```
COwnerList::COwnerList(void)
{
    here = car->owners.begin();
    i = 0;
    in = car->owners.end() - car->owners.begin();
}
```

interesting is it doesnt crash after 1st for in main(), so there must be something wrong in the code between those 2 for cycles in main(), but i have no idea what it could be i am not modifying anything related to ListOwners() there

**EDIT1**

Car constructor:

```
Car::Car(  const string & pid,
           const unsigned int & pvin = 0,
           const string & cname = "",
           const string & csurname = "")
{
    rz = pid;
    VIN = pvin;
    name = cname;
    surname = csurname;
}
```

**EDIT2**

```
class COwnerList
 {
   public:
    COwnerList(void);
    string         Name         ( void ) const;
    string         Surname      ( void ) const;
    bool           AtEnd        ( void ) const;
    void           Next         ( void );
    //vector<pair<string, string> > powners;
    const Car *car;
    int in;
   private:
    vector<pair<string, string> >::const_iterator here;
    int i;
 };
```

Comment: There are too many spaces.

Comment: What is in `lower_bound()` and what is in the constructor `Car()` ?

Comment: it crashes on this line COwnerList tmp; in second call

Comment: But you say it is after the first `for`, so the other lines have already executed a couple of times. `Segmentation faults` are not always due to the code where it seems to fail, in previous lines you may have made damage to the memory, and just in that `COwnerList tmp` line the damage becomes evident.

Comment: first for works fine, ill add car cosntructor code

Comment: The `Car()` constructor seems OK. But I see you are storing a pointer to an element from a `vector` . I don't see how you are using it, but you know it will only be valid as far as you don't modify the underlying vector. Don't you? Because once you add a new element to a vector, there is no guarantee that it is not going to reallocate all the elements in other memory address.

Comment: I am modifying vector indeed, i just didnt show that code because i thought it was irrelevant, but which line fo the code exactly are you talking about?        is it tmp.car = &(*it); ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74036/discussion-between-lllook-and-mondkin).

Comment: Your debugger should tell you which line of code is responsible for the crash.

Comment: it crashes on this line here = car->owners.begin(); but how do i fix it

Comment: @lllook You also need to show us what `COwnerList` consists of.  You are returning it by value in your `ListOwners` function, meaning that it requires correct copy semantics.  If not, then the behavior of the program is undefined.

Comment: This is the first line in your post that mentions the variable named `car`. What do you expect to happen at this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the car pointer is not initialized during the call in the COwnerList constructor. In the first loop, you might have got lucky. Things like this happens all the time. Sometimes the OS won't throw a seg fault everytime when you are calling a code which is not allocated yet.

Just put a condition guard in your code like this:

```
if (car != NULL) {    
    here = car->owners.begin();
    i = 0;
    in = car->owners.end() - car->owners.begin();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is more likely you are modifying the vector after saving that `tmp.toto` pointer to the vector's internal storage.

Note that when you do `tmp.car = &(*it)` you are making a pointer towards the internal storage of the vector.

If later you call `push_back()` on the vector, you cannot rely in the pointers that you had before, because the vector can reallocate its contents in other memory addresses after you call the `push_*` methods.

Also note that a debugger may not tell the exact line that has to be corrected, even if the crash happens there. The debugger may tell you the first line where the problem is evident, but the cause of the problem may have happened several lines before.